# How to use an array formula inside a sumif without having to " " specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

The currently formula I am using is =SUM(SUMIFS(Sheet2!E:E,Sheet2!$B:$B,A19,Sheet2!$A:$A,{"704","213"}))

This is a array inside a sumif function. However for the last part {"704","213"}, I would like to reference cell reference instead of a text string. When I change  {"704","213"} to {B12,B13} I get an error "There's a problem with this formula". Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of your sheet and maybe end result? Also, you have a VBA tag, have you tried anything through VBA? if so, can you provide the code. It will help to understand your issue

Answer (score 0):

I finally found an answer, by using a sumproduct function first and then using a sumifs.